# Update data in database with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update data in my database with Mongoose and NodeJS I can get the data from the loggedin user already but it won't let me update. In my front-end I render a form that get data from the loggedin user *(views/pages/profile-edit.ejs)*.

In the backend user.js file I have this :

```js
    .get('/profile-edit',  auth, (req, res) => { 
        try {
            const user = req.user
            res.render('pages/profile-edit', { user } ) 
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
    .post('/profile-edit', auth, async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const user = req.user
            await user.findOneAndUpdate()
            res.redirect('/profile')
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
```

In the .post I store the loggedin user in the const user. In the await user.findOneAndUpdate I try to update but I does nothing. I only got redirect to my profile page. I don't get any error, but data isn't updated in the database.

This is my Mongoose model :

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }, 
    gender: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    club: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    searchGender: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }, 
    tokens: [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        }
    }]
})

// SOURCE : https://medium.com/swlh/jwt-authentication-authorization-in-nodejs-express-mongodb-rest-apis-2019-ad14ec818122
// This code is running bevore we save the object to the database. Here we hash the password with the package bcrypt.
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const user = this
    if(user.isModified('password')){
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
    }
    next()
})

// Here we create a token with JWT. The sign expects data that will be used to sign the token. 
// Once the token created save it to the list of tokens and return the token. 
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function() {
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign ({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_KEY)
    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token})
    await user.save()
    return token
}

// Here we search for the User we expext 2 parameters email & password. First search for the user by email, if we can't find it throw an error.
// If it is found we compare the password with the hashed password in the database. 
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error({ error: 'Geen geldig emailadres gevonden in de database' })
    }
    const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!isPasswordMatch) {
        throw new Error({ error: 'Wachtwoord klopt niet' })
    }
    return user
}

// Here we create the model called User and bind it to the userSchema then we export it. 
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

This is a link to my repo on GitHub so you can view the whole code [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Roene/Dating-app)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `user.findOneAndUpdate()` doesn't work like that, as that func needs a `filter` to filter the docs(find the doc to be updated) & an `update`(what has to be updated) !! There is one function `.save()` which works on mongoose object but here its not, So what's there in `req.user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is problematic:

```js
await user.findOneAndUpdate()
```

Because [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) is a method of model itself (in this case User).
Also to be able to use `findOneAndUpdate` method, you need a filter and update object so that it can find the document with given filter, and update it's content with the update object, like  this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: ".."}, {firstname: "..."} );
```

You have already the user document which is passed to req.user, so I guess you can just update it's fields, and use the [save()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) method.

```js
.post('/profile-edit', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const user = req.user;

      user.firstname = req.body.firstname; // this is just a sample, you may need to change it

      await user.save();
      res.redirect('/profile')
  } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
  }
})
```

If this doesn't work, you can try using findByIdAndUpdate method like this:

```js
.post('/profile-edit', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const user = req.user;

      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {
          firstname: req.body.firstname
      })

      res.redirect('/profile')
  } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id, {
          firstname: req.body.firstname},
          {new: true}
 )
```

The new option ensures that the modified document rather than the original is returned. New is set to false by default so please don't miss this.